# Laravel livewire data disappearing

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have extremely simple render function with livewire but the data are disappearing from blade after a second.

`component`

```
public function render()
{
  $spotlight = Project::orderby('created_at', 'desc')->where('published', '=', 'y')->with('user')->offset(5)->take(5)->latest()->get();
  return view('livewire.index.job-spotlight', compact('spotlight'));
}
```

`view`

```
<div>
    <h3 class="margin-bottom-5">Panel name</h3>

    <div id="job-spotlight" class="showbiz-container">
        <div class="showbiz" data-left="#showbiz_left_1" data-right="#showbiz_right_1" data-play="#showbiz_play_1" >
            <div class="overflowholder">
                <ul>
                    @foreach($spotlight as $spots)
                    <li wire:poll.keep-alive>
                    {{$spots->title}}
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note::** there is a `wire:poll.keep-alive` on `<li>` tag.

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

When following the docs you can see that they recommend using the mount function so try something like this. I know it may seem a bit too much for a problem like this, but for future uses it will make thing a lot more "readable"..

```
component

public $spotlight;

public function mount(Spotlight $spotlight) *or it can be ()*
{
    $this->spotlight = Project::orderby('created_at', 'desc')->where('published', '=', 'y')->with('user')->offset(5)->take(5)->latest()->get();
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.index.job-spotlight', [
        'spotlight' => $this->spotlight,
    ]);
}
```

This should work because you are creating and setting the varible properly, I dont think that the `wire:poll.keep-alive` on `<li>` tag really makes a difference. Let me know if this helps, again I know its a lot of code for a small function but for any future addition to the blade it will make things easier.